# How to define comment characters for React JSX in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3, reactjs

In OSX, in Sublime Text 3 (build 3065), with syntax set as `JavaScript(JSX)` or just `JSX`, I'm hitting the usual
<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> to comment out the selected text.

However, ST3 is defaulting to the `//` comment chars, when I want to wrap selection like this:

`{/* foobar selected text */}`

I'm looking in here, but can't figure out what to edit:

`/Users/admin/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/JavaScript (JSX).tmLanguage`

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: For future reference, [tag:jsx] is something unrelated to [tag:react-jsx].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create an XML file in `Packages/User` called `Comments.tmPreferences` with the following contents (I'm assuming the base scope of your language is `source.jsx` - you can find this in the `.tmLanguage` file):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Comments</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>source.jsx</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>shellVariables</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>TM_COMMENT_START</string>
                <key>value</key>
                <string>// </string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>TM_COMMENT_START_2</string>
                <key>value</key>
                <string>{/* </string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>TM_COMMENT_END_2</string>
                <key>value</key>
                <string> */}</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>uuid</key>
    <string>F9BFFF1F-1999-4722-B094-52E8AFD234D1</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

`//` will remain the default comment prefix when you hit <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>, but when you select some text and hit <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> you will wrap it in `{/* blahblahblah */}`.

If you want to completely get rid of `//`, use the following instead:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Comments</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>source.jsx</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>shellVariables</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>TM_COMMENT_START</string>
                <key>value</key>
                <string>{/* </string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>TM_COMMENT_END</string>
                <key>value</key>
                <string> */}</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>uuid</key>
    <string>F9BFFF1F-1999-4722-B094-52E8AFD234D1</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Thanks! ... This seems good for doing `{/* */}` comments, but not for undoing ... Your solution leaves the curlies when you hit `command + /` while caret is on the line, with no selection ... typical `command + /` behavior removes all comment chars. But I'm not complaining, this is helpful when writing .jsx

Comment: PS: for other folks: I had to change `scope` to `source.js` instead of `source.jsx` for this solution to work. I know this changes comment behavior for .js files, but as front-end dev I'm dealing with mostly .jsx syntax. Thanks @MattDMo, accepting your answer now.

Comment: Dunno if you'd be up for it, but I think it would be awesome if you turned this into an actual sublime package! Thanks for the code!

Comment: Where are the key bindings defined? Just curious, why it binds to ⌘Shift /

Comment: @SidaZhou it's defined in the default key bindings. Go to Preferences -> Key Bindings-Default and search for `comment`.

Comment: @OlehZiniak yes. If you select text and hit the shortcut, it will be commented out. If you hit the shortcut again, the comment characters will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

While the previous answer solves the problem partially, it doesn't remove the comments correctly.

I added a [plugin](https://github.com/borela/naomi/blob/master/plugin/commands/ToggleJsxComment.py) to https://github.com/borela/naomi which correctly detects the required comment type to use, it works for line and block comments.